# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use "static" when no class scope is active in /vendor/o2syste m/o2glob/src/Helpers/Inflector.php on line 121 - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know where this error comes from. I just cloned our group Laravel project, then I did composer install, but the result is like this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use "static" when no class scope is active in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mxvistore-web/vendor/o2syste
m/o2glob/src/Helpers/Inflector.php on line 121
```

Comment: Are other projects work fine with your lampp server?

Comment: fine, i don't know, but my friend vendor folders don't have o2system, where did it come from?